# Trigger function when carousel set to autoplay in Glidejs

Tags: javascript, carousel, glidejs

I have a GlideJS carousel and I'm trying to call my `handleAnimation` function after each slide becomes active.

It works if I click on it, but I don't know how to get it to run when the carousel is on autoplay.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  const carousel = new Glide(this.myRef.current, {
    autoplay: 3000,
    rewind: true,
  })
  carousel.mount()

  const myTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".slide__trigger")
  myTriggers.forEach(trigger => {
    const triggerStep = trigger.getAttribute("data-step")
    trigger.addEventListener("click", () =>
      this.handleAnimation(triggerStep)
    )
  })
}
```

Should I be using one of GlideJS's event handlers? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are event handlers you have to use it for sure.

Regarding Glide docs there are events fires once the item becomes active, you can use `run` or `move` events to run your function when the animation starts:

```
carousel.on('move', this.handleAnimation(triggerStep))
```

and use `move.after` or `run.after` to run after the animation ends:

```
carousel.on('move.after', this.handleAnimation(triggerStep))
```

If those events didn't match your needs try another event.
https://glidejs.com/docs/events

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your assistance.